# Edit HTML in Java

Tags: jsp

I want to know how to make my dynamically generated table in jsp editable and make changes and save edited data in database also.

```
<table style="background-color: green" border="2">  
    <tr>  
        <td><div class="tab"><font color="white">Policy No.</font></div></td>  
        <td><div class="tab"><font color="white">Policy Name</font></div></td>  
        <td><div class="tab"><font color="white">Creation Date</font></div></td>  
        <td><div class="tab"><font color="white">Description</font></div></td>  
    </tr>  
<table>
```

Comment: That's fine. But you aren't clear on at what step exactly you're stucking. Please elaborate. Are you able to create basic HTML forms with basic HTML inputs? The principle isn't that much different in JSP as it's merely a HTML code generator; you just have to make sure that your JSP generates exactly *that* HTML.

Comment: By the way, the HTML `<font>` tag is deprecated since 1998. If I were you, I'd doublecheck if you're really reading proper and up to date tutorials/resources while learning JSP/HTML.

Comment: -1: Please include more information. A detailed answer to his question would be in pages. A short answer would be to use DOM manipulation through javascript combined with ajax.